# Structure analysis based on direct stiffness method. Solve taking too much time

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

The program generates a very large matrix based on some input from the user. The matrix is symmetric and called generalstifnessmatrix. It also generates 2 other lists(displacement and forces list) both having a certain number of unknowns. Heres an example of a displacement list:

```
disp={0,0,0,D [1], 0,0,D [2],D [3]}
```

And an example of a force list:

```
forces={f [1],F [2],F [3]-50,100,F [5],F [6],0,0}
```

Then I solve for the unknowns D and F using the following method:

```
Solve [Thread [generalstifnessmatrix.disp==forces],{Cases [disp,Except [_Integer]],Cases [disp,Except [_Integer]]}]
```

Is there anyway I could benefit from the symmetry to make it quicker? Or anything else? The generalstifnessmatrix has lots of zero elements. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser you can see above that disp has some elements with known values it's not entirely made of variables so LinearSolve wont work.

Comment: Note that `D` is a built-in function, so your first line does not do what I'm guessing you'd expect it to do (but that can be fixed by changing `D` to `d` or some other non-built-in symbol). Could you give an example `stiffnessmatrix` for people to use?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus here's an example of a relatively small generalstifnessmatrix   {{1,0,0,-2,0,0}, {0,6,10,0,-8,25}, {0,25,13,0,-13,0}, {-1,0,0,2,0,0}, {0,-6,-10,0,8,-25}, {0,-25,-13,0,13,0}}

Comment: @user20037: That doesn't work; `disp` has 8 elements, and your matrix is 6x6.

Comment: Different examples imagine any 8x8 matrix with the lists shown above in the main question. The matrix are usually larger than 50x50 and the disp list has 50 entries.

Comment: @MichaelE2: The issue is that both `disp` and `forces` contain unknown symbols, which means it isn't quite the same as a matrix inversion problem. It can still be solved with similar methods though (if I understand the question correctly, at least).

Comment: @MichaelE2: Maybe I'm not understanding things correctly, but executing `disp == Inverse[generalstifnessmatrix].forces` just gives an expression similar to the original `generalstifnessmatrix.disp==forces`, and doesn't make it any easier to solve for the variables. This happens since both `disp` and `forces` have unknowns present, so you just get a bunch of linear equations after applying the inverse, so the situation isn't changed. In a standard linear algebra problem, applying the inverse to both sides immediately gives the solution, but this isn't a standard linear algebra problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2: "If the 4th entry of disp is d[1], then d[1] is equal to the fourth entry of Inverse[generalstifnessmatrix].forces, right?" True. But in this case, the fourth entry of `Inverse[generalstifnessmatrix].forces` is a long expression containing a bunch of variables, so you still don't know what `d[1]` is (hence what I meant when I said the problem is unchanged by applying the inverse). In a typical linear algebra problem, the fourth entry of `Inverse[generalstifnessmatrix].forces` would be a number, and so you would immediately know that `d[1]` was equal to it. That's not the case here.

Comment: @MichaelE2: No worries, it's a weird problem and it confused me at first too (it reminds me of a llama in sheep's clothing).

Answer (score 8):

Nasser pointed out that typically in stiffness-matrix problems (and linear algebra in general), one usually solves an $Ax=b$ system where $A,b$  are known and $x$ is unknown. Having $A$ known, and both $x$ and $b$ containing a mixture of knowns and unknowns is presumably not common, and thus your question isn't *quite* a standard linear algebra problem.

However, if you are sure that this is what you want to do, then the problem can be refactored as a standard linear algebra problem. For example, define `disp`, `forces`, and `stiffnessMatrix`:

```
disp = {0, 0, 0, d[1], 0, 0, d[2], d[3]};
forces = {f[1], f[2], f[3] - 50, 100, f[5], f[6], 0, 0};
stiffnessMatrix = # + #\[Transpose] &@
   RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {8, 8}];
```

Now define the set of equations and variables:

```
eqn = Thread[stiffnessMatrix.disp == forces];
vars = {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[5], f[6], d[1], d[2], d[3]};
```

We can then recast the original mixed-variable $Ax=b$ problem as an auxiliary problem $m_1y=-m_0$ where $m_1,m_0$ are purely numeric, and $y$ is purely symbolic, thus reducing it to a standard linear algebra problem:

```
{m0, m1} = CoefficientArrays[eqn, vars];
c = LinearSolve[m1, -m0];
stiffnessMatrix.disp == forces /. Thread[vars -> c]

(*True*)
```

For larger examples, you may want to add an `N@` in front of `CoefficientArrays[...]` to avoid the problem of exact arithmetic being used.

Comment: This is a nice solution.  Machine reals sometimes incur too much round-off to get `True` in the last test. The norm of the residual is about 10^-14 in some cases, so that's good enough for me to be considered equivalent.  I might worry what happens in a large system though.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Yeah, I have no idea how badly using floats might mess up a large system for the OP's problem.